# .html() not working in second id but is in first id

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you press button it calls randomQuote() function using onClick method in html. It works fine , changes the background color and the text of quotes[rand] also works. But there is no change in by id element. Also, it is not a array problem because if i type the same by statement outside the randomQuote(), it works fine.

Here is the code:

```
function randomQuote(){
var rand =Math.floor(Math.random()*(quotes.length)); 
$("#qu").html(quotes[rand]); 
$("#by").html(by[rand]);
$("body").animate({backgroundColor: colorr[rand]}, 1000); 
};
```

(Go to https://codepen.io/TheCoder21/pen/XVVxvo) for full code

Comment: _"Go to https://codepen.io/TheCoder21/pen/XVVxvo for full code"_ No. Add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) in the question and not only a link to an external resource.

Comment: What is `by` in `$("#by").html(by[rand]);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your markup:

```
 <div class="quote">
    <blockquote id="qu">
       Here are some of my favourite quotes.Hope you enjoy them!   
       <p id="by">
         random text
       </p>
    </blockquote>
 </div>
```

container with id="by" overwrites by this jquery method $("#qu").html(quotes[rand]); 
If you want to prevent this behaviour just wrap your text in new paragraph with id="qu":

```
<blockquote>
    <p id="by">
       Here are some of my favourite quotes.Hope you enjoy them!   
    </p>
    <p id="by">
       random text
    </p>
</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `by` element belongs inside `blockguote` i.e `id=qu` element when you did `$("#qu").html(quotes[rand]);`
It's html structure got changes. you no longer have a `by` element.
Therefore, when you try to `$("#by").html(by[rand]);` nothing happens. Because no `by` element was found.

Solution: move your `by` element outside the `blockquote`

Working code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MrLodd

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate the id in two paragraphs inside the blockquote. You can't give the blockquote and id and then expect the paragraph tag to also pick up an id inside of it. The blockquote overrides it.

```
<blockquote>
<p id="qu">
Here are some of my favourite quotes.Hope you enjoy them!   
  <p>
  <p id="by">
    random text
  </p>
</blockquote>
```